# Change timezone in php with no affect on datetime functions used

Tags: php

How to change my php setting timezone from CST to EST? Is there a way with just putting a line on top of each page? Or would I need to change every date function?
Because I have some codes which are used like this :

```
$charge_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($value6[0] . " - 7 day"))
```

And

```
$string_jsdate_wed  = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($string_date_wed . ' ' . $arr_wed[1]));
```

And Im afraid it would clash?

Comment: you can use date_default_timezone_set

Comment: And what else so it becomes EST? @vSugumar

Comment: Please refer this http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php you can set date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata') if you are from india

Comment: No Im in america but I want the EST timezone, which state do I chose?

Comment: which state you are from refer this http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.america.php

Comment: new york @vSugumar Does this work   date_default_timezone_set('US/Eastern');? or I should do this 
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York')

Comment: date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York')